# Paint in Water - action verb?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

Is there a verb describing the way paint mingles with water and forms those amazing shapes, almost smoke-like.

Comment: There's invariably some external "stirring" or internal "circulatory" force involved, which leads to ***swirling*** patterns rather than amorphous ***diffusion***.

Comment: Yeah, technically "diffuse", but it is far from capturing the poetry of the effect you describe.  "Kaleidoscope" or "phantasm" might capture the allusion better.

Comment: Not a particularly intuitive duplicate, but this question will form a pointer to that one.

Comment: Not sure how a question asking for a **noun** (a word for certain patterns, **none** of which involves paint in water [[as shown here](http://twistedsifter.com/2013/04/high-speed-photographs-of-ink-dropped-into-water/)]) could be confused w/one asking for a **verb** describing the way paint mingles w/water, but on this Armistice Day I suppose I should respectfully defer to the reason of veterans here who feel otherwise. After all, “...ours but to do and die."  Or does it openvote? Anyway, I'll dignify your good question w/the suggestion of "plume":To spread out in a shape resembling a feather.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe **diffuse** is the word you are looking for (second bullet):

[image]

[Google definition link.](https://www.google.com/search?q=diffuse%20definition&oq=diffuse%20definition&aqs=chrome..69i57.3823j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)